# Accept a server-side, arbitrary-size upload in non-Rails Ruby?

Tags: ruby, upload, cgi

I've got PHP code to accept uploads, but I have no idea how to make that happen in Ruby.  While I'm not opposed to Rails, per se, I'm not looking to involve the whole ecosystem, and, instead, am just looking for how to receive a POSTed file in a plain-Jane CGI (or CGI-esque) Ruby script.  Any suggestions/gems, etc.?

Comment: CGI? Nobody does that any more. The closest thing to that is a thin [Rack app](https://github.com/rack/rack) built using something like [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) if you don't want or need the whole Rails environment.

Comment: Getting a full Rails stack up and running can be more involved than bare-bones PHP, but it also gives you a lot more tools like [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) to manage your uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a gem such as [net-http-server](https://github.com/postmodern/net-http-server):

```
require 'net/http/server'
require 'pp'

Net::HTTP::Server.run(:port => 8080) do |request,stream|
  pp request

  [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Hello World']]
end
```

But of course you certainly can go even deeper down the stack:

https://blog.appsignal.com/2016/11/23/ruby-magic-building-a-30-line-http-server-in-ruby.html

Comment: Thanks!  I don't really keep track of my StackOverflow and associated site accounts, so I can't + your answer, but that does seem as if it might let me do what I'm wanting to make happen.  Appreciated!